# SSIS dynamic connectiong string via environment variable failed to execute

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I want to test dynamic connection string in SSIS. Here were the steps that I already performed.

1) Created connection string.
2) Parameterizing connection string
3) Deploy SSIS Package to SSIS Catalog via Project deployment model
4) Setup environment variable in SSIS Catalog
5) Configure SSIS project to reference environment variable

Everything look goods but failed to execute the task.

SSIS Catalog

[image: SSIS Catalog]

Project configuration

[image]

Error message

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you upload your sample package here ?

Comment: The solution worked if deployed to the same server as defined in environment variable. Something interesting....

Answer (score 1):

I think you should fix the issue with the steps below:

1. Create a Proxy account with permissions in SSISDB and the permissions needed for the db used in the package.
2. Create a credential in the SSIS server. The user and password are the same that the proxy account.
3. Use the proxy account to execute the project.

Answer (score 0):

As per the screenshot, it looks like the package is failing due to login issue. Please check the login with which the package is running and it has correct access to DB Server.